# Event when HttpRequest Ends?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, webforms

I am using asp.net forms. There is a `Page_Load` event,but is there an end event?

I have a linq datacontext created on pageload and I would like to dispose it when I am done.

Comment: I presume  you're using LINQ to SQL?

Comment: If you're using LinqToSQL then you should not have a context created on Page_Load. You should wrap context in using {} statement, put them in a Data Access Layer, and access methods from the Data Access Layer within your ASP.net page as needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should probably do it on `Page_Unload` Event is the last event in page life cycle. For more on page events check out [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

As Emmanuel N stated, there is `Page_Unload` event. However, if you use `using`, you do not need to worry about disposing `DataContext`.

Here is an [example](http://www.thereforesystems.com/linq-to-sql-tutorial/).

```
protected void buttonSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  using (var context = new NorthwindDataContext())
  {
    var customers =
      from c in context.Customers
      select c;

    gridViewCustomers.DataSource = customers;
    gridViewCustomers.DataBind();
  }
}
```

[Using is better than Dispose.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1034656/296861)

Answer (score 0):

By the way if you are using Entity Framework, you don't have to dispose DbContext: the default behaviour is to open connection when needed and close it when done ([more details](http://blog.jongallant.com/2012/10/do-i-have-to-call-dispose-on-dbcontext.html#.UUN4_hwwp2M)).